# how to create dynamic link list from .lnk files in a folder with powershell

Tags: powershell, winforms, dynamic-variables

I would like to be able to create a dynamic link list from .lnk files in a folder with powershell. I want the link list to be presented to the user in a form that can be minimzed, but will stay active for the entire session, even if the user launch one of them the main form will remain active.

I'm having a hard time moving from VBS to powershell, so any help would be appreciated.

Finally I have managed to have a begining of solution here is my code.

```
$linklist = @(
("MyFisrtApp" , "\\Path\To\MyFisrtApp.exe"),
("MySecondApp" , "\\Path\To\MySecondApp.exe"),
("MyThirdApp" , "\\Path\To\MyThirdApp.exe"),
("MyFourthApp" , "\\Path\To\MyFourthApp.exe")
)

#Create Form Object
$mainform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$mainform.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,300)
$mainform.Text = " My Virtual Applications"
$mainform.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" #loads the window in the center of the screen

# convert the array of arrays into an ordered Hashtable
$linkHash = [ordered]@{}
$linklist | ForEach-Object { $linkHash[$_[0]] = $_[1] }

$calculatedPosition =40

$linkHash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $lnk = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
    $lnk.Text = $_.Name   # set the name for the label
    $lnk.Tag  = $_.Value  # store the link url inside the control's Tag property
    $lnk.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(60, $calculatedPosition)
    # inside the scriptblock, $this refers to the LinkLabel control itself
    $lnk.Add_Click({ Start-Process $this.Tag })
    $mainform.Controls.Add($lnk)
    $calculatedPosition += 40   # just a guess, you may want different vertical spacing
}

#Show Form
$mainform.ShowDialog()
```

My next move now is to display the icon of the .lnk file on the left of each link and also dynamically construct the linklist hashtable from the properties of a list of .lnk files in a specific folder. Also having the form to auto-size as needed if more links need to be shown, would be interesting. I'm trying different setting with mitigated results.

Comment: What information would you like to display for each .lnk file? The name of the shortcut file itself? The name/path of the target file? Something else?

Comment: What exact problem do you have with the code? Please edit the question to include the code you have so far (in text form, formatted as code), what it is expected to do and what it actually does (including any error message in text form).

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen : I would like to display clickable icons (shortcut), it is a way to hide the real shortcuts and their location from lambda users and prevent them from deleting them.

Comment: It sounds like a lot of details and context is missing from your post. What is a "lambda user"? Why do you need to protect them from deleting shortcuts? How will you be deploying the script?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen: Lambda users are the ones that often delete shortcuts by mistake and if the shortcut is in their profile it's gone, and when those shortcuts are for ThinApp support has to unregerister and reregister the ThinApp for the shortcut to be recreated. So if we take the shortcut out of the user profile and don't give them access to the real shortcut they can't delete them. Thus saving calls to support. The shortcut validation part as to security group membership is already done and constructed dynamically at each logon. The script will be executed at user login.